# How to bias the MOST current mirror?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, bias, current-mirror

I am looking for a simple tutorial or decent primer. Because all what I've found yet is so not helpful. Could you please help me?

f.e. how to make 5u output current using a p-MOS current mirror...

Comment: Try page 42. Primer on what? Bias what now? Found what? What are you asking about? Don't be shy.

Comment: I've heard from someone Dulux might make a good primer.

Comment: The question is simple; I can connect two transistors with arbitrary parameters to form a simple current mirror. However, how to control the current.

f.e. how to make 5u output current using a p-MOS current mirror...

Comment: Edit your question with the details from this comment please.

Comment: Are you asking about fiber optics for in-vehicle entertainment systems ([MOST](http://www.mostcooperation.com/))?

Comment: What's a "MOST" current mirror?  Also, "5u" isn't a measure of current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key in solving this is to bias one Mosfet properly such that you get a current source with known current Id.

And lets say you also know the dimension of the MOSFET which is acting as the current source, knowing these factors you can make a current mirror in any branch in the circuit by dimensioning the MOSFET same as the current source MOSFET(Of course you should connect the gate of the previous current source MOSFET to the gate of this MOSFET too).

So the main factor is designing that initial current source MOSFET. We know the formula for the MOSFET that is Id= Un*Cox ((Vgs-Vt)^2)W/L, you should be given the Un and Cox values in the questions or if your Simulating check the values for the technology selected from the PDF provided (There should be one or annotate DC operating points and view the DC parameters) and Vt should also be known. So the unknowns are W,L and Vgs. Select your own W/L ratio and you left with only Vgs. Have a diode connected current source self biased stage. This makes Vgs=Vds, Lets say Vs=0 so by controlling Vd you control the entire current source. Now you have one known current source. This Vd is decided by the designer and depending on this Vd value we chose a resistor which would drop certain voltage across it leaving only the needed Vd (Kirchoffs Voltage law).

As mentioned earlier you can easily make a current mirror in any other branch ! Important is that the MOSFETs are in Saturation.

Answer (score 0):

*how to make 5u output current using a p-MOS current mirror*

Simple: **You can't**.

A current mirror, **mirrors** the current. It would actually be more accurate to say it **copies** the current.

So it will not *by itself* generate that 5 uA you want.

What a current mirror can do is:
- Copy a 5 uA current you already have so you can use the copy for something else
- copy a for example 1 uA current and multiply if by 5 so you get 5 uA
- copy a 10 uA current and multiply by 0.5 so you get 5 uA

- make multiple copies of all currents as mentioned above if you use multiple outputs.

The essence of a current mirror is that it converts a current into a voltage by using a transistor, that voltage is fed to an **identical** transistor to re-create that current value. You can use multiple identical transistors or transistors with a certain size ratio (but always keep channel length the same for MOSFETs) to make the current ratios you need.

But you need a current to start with !

Answer (score 0):

A standard PMOS current mirror (as with all current mirrors) has a programming side and an output side (which is where the current is *mirrored*)

I am not going to do the equations for you, but here is the idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY2MYj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rp pulls the gate of M2 to the on state (into [saturation or active mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Modes_of_operation)), and will therefore have some Vgs for the actual drain current.

This is the *programming* side of the mirror.

Assuming M2 and M1 are perfectly matched, then for some Vgs vs Id in M2, the same drain current will flow as the Vgs asserted to both devices is identical, and the current in M2 is therefore *mirrored* into M1.

That current will be constant provided Vpos does not change.

As FM mentioned, a more usual implementation is to generate a current for the drain of M2, but this circuit would operate as well, provided the output voltage is within the compliance range of the FETs.

You can find the details of calculating a specific current [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror)